# Setting the TCCL in WildFly/JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, classnotfoundexception, wildfly

I am encountering the problem discussed [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/171407?start=0&tstart=0) which leads to a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected/__DatatypeFactory` error.

In the above thread, Jason Greene says "...make sure you set TCCL to point to your module classloader (and reset it back to the original in finally block)". I would like to try this but cannot figure out how to set the TCCL or get the module classloader. **How can I set the TCCL to the module classloader?**

Additional Information:

- I encounter the error when marshalling XML with JAXB
- I am using WildFly 8.0.0.CR1

Answer (score 2):

The answer ended up being surprisingly simple (for my context!) I had a class that had the correct TCCL context in it.

This would be the class that has the correct loader when it is initialized

```
public class GoodClass {

    private ClassLoader goldenLoader;

    public GoodClass() {
        // the class loader must be the 'correct' one at this point. We save the 'correct' one for later
        this.goldenLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    }

    public static ClassLoader getGoodClassLoader() {
        return goldenLoader;
    }
}
```

This would be the class that has the TCCL and __redirected/__DatatypeFactory problems

```
public class BadClass {
    public void myMethod() {

        ClassLoader origLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        try {
            // you can NOT do stuff that relies on the set TCCL here
            ClassLoader goldenLoader = GoodClass.getGoodClassClassLoader().getGoldenLoader();
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(goldenLoader);
            // you CAN do stuff that relies on the set TCCL here
        } finally {
            // use this if you need to restore the orignal loader
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(origLoader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reseting the class loader needs to be done in a finally block.

Comment: Good call @JamesR.Perkins. Updated per your suggestion. Is it imperative to ALWAYS revert the classloader or is this only needed if your swapped in classloader doesn't do everything the original one does?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely imperative to always revert the TCCL even if it's null. You never know what other components/dependencies are going to try to do the same thing.